# git: I accidentally merged feature branch into master instead of develop

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I'm using git and working with master/develop/feature branches.

The master only had the README file. And, unfortunately, I accidentally merged the feature branch I was working into the master instead the develop branch. And also removed the feature branch.

I know little about git and I'm confused about what to do. But I think the right thing is to merge the changes on the feature branch (already removed) into develop and revert the merge into the master. But how to do that if I already removed the feature branch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that I'm assuming here that you haven't `push`ed the results of the merge.  If you have, this still can work, but would require a "force push" which in turn impacts everyone else using the repo (see "recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` docs; as that's essentially the situation it would create).  But if you haven't, you don't need to worry about any of that.  So:

First thing is to recreate the feature branch.  I'm assuming it only ever existed locally.  (If it had been pushed before the merge, you might be able to recover it from the remote; but either way the approach below will work.)  So

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature
git reset --hard HEAD^2
```

Now the feature branch is restored to the merge commit's "second parent" - which should be where it was before the merge.

Next you need to remove the merge from `master`.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

And that's it; you're ready to merge the feature into the development branch.

Comment: I've already pushed the merge. I'm studying the git rebase now.

Answer (score 3):

First checkout master branch using `git checkout master`, and create a new branch called `feature` from master branch:

```
git checkout -b feature
```

Again checkout master branch, and run the following command:

```
git log
```

This should give list of commits you have on master branch. You need to scroll through commit list, to copy the commit id that you want to revert to. Suppose that id is `advcf456yhn8`, then you need to write the command:

```
git reset --hard advcf456yhn8
```

This will revert all changes & revert back to actual content at specific commit id.

Now you have created a branch `feature`, which you can merge into `develop`. Simply do `git checkout develop` & merge `feature` branch by using `git merge feature`.

Also by running the following command, you can get your entire commit history:

```
git reflog
```

Comment: Not sure if you're aware, but the example ID you gave is invalid; a commit ID consists of hex digits (0-9 and a-f) only.  Also there are somewhat simpler commands to do this that avoid having to work directly with commit ID anyway.  And I would advise removing the merge from both branches

Comment: I just gave an example, nothing more. He mentioned that he is new to git, so giving a basic run down on reverting changes was a better idea in my opinion.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that. But I was afraid that the reset in the master branch could change the new feature branch.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way of Getting back the master to previous commit :

1. clone you master repository
2. If you are using any GUI on git, Use option "revert" to select the particular commit ID
3. Once reverted, Kindly commit and push to master.

CMD:

1. git clone master
2. git reset --hard HEAD^
3. git commit -m ""
4. git push

Comment: The commit in question is a merge.  There are several complications trying to revert a merge, including that the commands as provided won't work.  Also, even when no merge is involved a revert does not return to a previous commit; it only updates content to a previous state.